# using jquery masked input for updating values

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

i have a problem with masked input plugin. in my header i have

```
$("#isNo").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

and my input field is;

```
<h:inputText value="#{bBean.PhoneNr}" id="isNo" />
```

so, when `bBean.PhoneNr` is empty, there is no problem, because textbox is rendered with null value in it. mask is successful. But when `bBean.PhoneNr` is something like 5123123123, if i dont click that text field, value remains same = 5123123123. if i click that text field it becomes (512) 312-3123. do you have an idea to correct that value to be masked before textbox clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fire 'click' event programmatically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#isNo").mask("(999) 999-9999").click();
});
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, i tried but it didn't work. i think click() evet occurs before setting the value of textfield, so i didn't get it worked. am i wrong?

Comment: I've specially tested - it works! http://jsfiddle.net/8QPhw/ - please see it. And it's working even without my "improvements" :) http://jsfiddle.net/8QPhw/1/

Comment: thank you, its completely my fault.. I was using maskedinput v1.0.. Changed to 1.3 solved it. both with click() and without click() works also..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the mask and reset it...

```
$("#isNo").val("NewPhoneNumber").unmask().mask("(999) 999-9999", {clearIfNotMatch: true});
```

This worked for me and should solve your problem!

**TLDR:** .unmask() before .mask()